# How to reorder categories for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

Is there a plugin available that will allow the drag and drop reordering of categories for a custom post type? Or suggestions on how to achieve reordering categories?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default 'category' taxonomy for your custom post type, you can just use the My Category Order plugin.

If you're using a custom hierarchical taxonomy, here's a modified version of the My Category Order plugin that works with custom taxonomies:

http://snipplr.com/view/48599/mycategoryorder-custom-taxonomy-mod/

Source: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-my-category-order-custom-taxonomy-order-and-code-improvements